# JPanel consuming entire JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I am creating a Java application which has a login screen. Right now I am designing the login screen. I use a `Panel` in a `JFrame`, which is positioned at `BorderLayout.CENTER`, and then set the layout of the `Panel` as `GridLayout(3,1)`. Right now my application looks like this:

[image: Rightnow how my image looks]

I want to design my `JFrame` like this:

[image: My design idea]

Here the grey portion is the `JFrame` and the red portion is the `Panel` which has the login screen, `TextField`'s and `Button`'s. I don't want the `TextField` and `Button`'s on the entire screen.

This is what I did right now

```
public class MailClient {

JFrame loginScreen;
JTextField emailid;
JPasswordField password;
JButton login;
Dimension loginScreenSize;
JPanel entireLogin;
BorderLayout mainLayout;

public static void main (String args[])
{
    MailClient obj = new MailClient();
    obj.build();
}
public void build()
{
    mainLayout = new BorderLayout(40, 40);

    loginScreenSize = new Dimension(300,300);

    loginScreen = new JFrame("MailClient");
    loginScreen.setSize(loginScreenSize);
    loginScreen.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    loginScreen.setResizable(false);
    loginScreen.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    loginScreen.setLayout(mainLayout);

    entireLogin = new JPanel();
    entireLogin.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));

    emailid = new JTextField();
    password = new JPasswordField();
    login = new JButton("LOGIN");

    entireLogin.add(emailid);
    entireLogin.add(password);
    entireLogin.add(login);

    loginScreen.add(entireLogin, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    loginScreen.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Comment: What do you want in the grey area? Empty space?

Comment: Empty space. I just want to put the login fields and submit button in the red area.

Comment: can you post your code please?

Comment: Do you need to use `BorderLayout`? I don't think it's a good choise here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an empty border of the thickness you find appropriate around the centered JPanel if you want it to have a border to the edge (if it resizes, for example).

```
myPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(int, int, int, int))
```

Set the maximum size for the centered JPanel if you want to prevent it from being made larger by the BorderLayout CENTER normal workings.

```
myPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(x, y))
```

Comment: *"Set the maximum size for the centered JPanel.."*  See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)